# SQL Where Not Exists throws an error at 'Where' clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert, not-exists

I'm trying to insert a row if the row does not already exist. I have followed up on different tutorials and this is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO UserTable (id,Email, userid) VALUES 
('"2424" + "','" + email + "','" + "4424"') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select * 
                  from UserTable 
                  where userid='"4424" + "' AND Email='" + email + "')
```

Basically trying to insert the afforementioned row if the table already does not contain the email variable and the user id "4424". This shows an error at the 'WHERE' clause.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S: I should be parameterizing them, but this is just to clarify the query

Comment: This depends on the **actual**, concrete database system you're using - not all SQL-based database product might handle this the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you can't use `WHERE` clause with `INSERT` statement. rather use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` construct like

```
INSERT INTO UserTable (id,Email, userid) 
SELECT 2424, email, 4424 FROM tbl1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select * 
                  from UserTable 
                  where userid='"4424" + "' AND Email='" + email + "');
```

Comment: So where's my insert values? The "2424" value?

Comment: @Earthling, see edit in answer if that helps. Use those values as column(s) in select query.

Comment: @Rahul, your second select is just wrong. Use `insert (<fields>) select <values> where not exists(...)` and you're done.

Comment: @Arvo, Hmm, yes cause that WHERE would not make any sense at all.

Comment: @Rahul, remove that `FROM tbl1` part either, otherwise you will insert many records again. You don't need `FROM` clause to select constant data.